# Прогрузка страницы в BS

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup, lxml, span

Загружаю с помощью beautiful soup ('lxml') страницу любого предмета стима, потом нахожу элемент id='market_commodity_forsale'.
[image: 1]

```py
@staticmethod
def get_item_cost(item_page):
    #print(item_page)
    r = requests.get(item_page)
    #print(r.text)
    parser = bs(r.text, "lxml")
    cost = parser.find("div", id="market_commodity_forsale")#class_='market_commodity_orders_header_promote')
    print(cost)
```

При этом при загрузке элемента внутреннее содержимое не выводится. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, подразумевается, что у вас уже установлены необходимые для работы скрипта библиотеки. Но, возможно, для кого-то это будет полезно. Поэтому, напомню, что нужно установить библиотеки с помощью команды в терминале:

```
pip install requests bs4 lxml
```

То, что вы пытаетесь получить, является динамически изменяемой величиной с помощью скриптов. Соответственно, в простом запросе вы не увидите нужных вам тегов. Но, если вы откроете инструменты разработчика и перейдете во вкладку "Network" -> "Fetch/XHR", станет понятно, каким способом получаются данные. В текущем случае данные прилетают после запроса в виде JSON, нужные вам поля которого, это HTML-разметка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, вы можете сделать запрос по тому же адресу, что и скрипт для получения нужных значений. Но, для достижения лучшего результата, лучше всего щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши по скрипту и выбрать пункт "Copy -> Copy asCURL (bash)",

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

перейти на сайт: https://curlconverter.com/, выбрать нужный вам язык, в данном случае Python и вставить скопированные значения. Ниже, на этой же странице вы увидите код, который можно использовать в вашем скрипте.
В данном случае описывается множество параметров, одним из которых является cookie. Я удалил данные значения, но в итоге скрипт не потерял своей работоспособности. Если вы хотите получить cookies от сайта, тогда посмотрите документацию requests по их получению и использованию.
И после всех проделанных манипуляций скрипт может приобрести следующий вид (это для разовой акции). Если вы планируете мучить сайт запросами постоянно, то лучше cookies все же получить.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
 
def get_source() -> (str, bool):
    headers = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru,en;q=0.9,uk;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'DNT': '1',
        'If-Modified-Since': 'Tue, 27 Feb 2024 00:34:30 GMT',
        'Referer': 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Kilowatt%20Case',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/120.0.0.0 YaBrowser/24.1.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "YaBrowser";v="24.1", "Yowser";v="2.5"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    }
 
    params = {
        'country': 'RU',
        'language': 'russian',
        'currency': '1',
        'item_nameid': '176413986',
        'two_factor': '0',
    }
    try:
        res = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram', params=params, headers=headers)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            return res.json()
        return False
    except ConnectionError:
        return False
 
 
def parse_lot(txt: str) -> (tuple, bool):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "lxml")
        if lots := soup.find_all("span", class_="market_commodity_orders_header_promote"):
            return lots[0].text, lots[1].text
        return False, False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False, False
 
 
def main() -> None:
    if data_json := get_source():
        buy_order_count, by_order_prise = parse_lot(data_json.get("buy_order_summary"))
        print(f'Запросов на покупку: {buy_order_count}, Начальная цена: {by_order_prise}')
        sell_order_count, sell_order_prise = parse_lot(data_json.get("sell_order_summary"))
        print(f'Лотов на продажу: {sell_order_count}, Начальная цена: {sell_order_prise}')
    else:
        print("Не удалось получить данные")
```

Обратите внимание, что здесь не производиться обработка при возвращении из функции парсинга значений False. Думаю, что обработать ее вы сможете нужным вам образом.

Comment: Гениально, спасибо. Успел сегодня реализовать через selenium, с потерей производительности, но ваш ответ - это лучшее, что можно сделать в моей ситуации. Рад, что вы нашли мой вопрос. вы большой _молодец_